# Calculate the integral of a $x!$

Tags: improper-integrals, factorial, gamma-function

How I can calculate this integral:

$$ \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{\mu^x}{x!}  dx$$

where $\mu$ is a constant number?

I tried to solve it using:

> Gamma function of Euler
>
> $\Gamma(x + 1) = x!$

But using this method I couldn't continue

Comment: You shall check for the convergence of the integral, first of all. Most probably there are different region of convergence, or less, due to what $\mu$ can be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It diverges.  As $x\to-\infty$, the integrand grows without bound, regardless of $\mu$.